# Как и где в Android Studio посмотреть количество запущенных services у приложения?

Tags: android, android-studio, service

Раньше эклипс я помню показывал какие и сколько сервисов у приложения запущено, а в AndroidStudio как посмотреть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Tools -> Android -> Monitor

Там отображаются процессы. Там же отображаются и сервисы.

Comment: Спасибо, вкладка Devicees открыта и вкладка File Explorer открыта, запускаю Service но не найду где он отображаться должен( Может они только c рутом видны?

Comment: Во вкладке Devices они отображаются. Но я не знаю, нужен ли root. Если запускать через эмулятор, то точно работает. А вот как с устройством не знаю.

Ты еще можешь проверить какие сервисы работают через сам телефон. Настройки -> Приложения -> Работающие -> Там находишь свое приложения, открываешь, и там будет список сервисов и процессов.

Comment: Спасибо, вот видео помогло разобраться http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZNPmf-2e0I